# How to properly auto-indent Org Mode multi-line list items?

Tags: org-mode

I am typing a journal entry in org-mode as so:

```
I worked on my English paper today, and made lots of progress.
+ We used Emacs for our project
+ Some other people used vi, but I think Emacs Org mode really helps
  + One of the groups even used LaTeX, but I think Emacs AucTeX might be the best way to write LaTeX
```

This is what happens when I press `RET` between AucTeX and might.

```
I worked on my English paper today, and made lots of progress.
+ We used Emacs for our project
+ Some other people used vi, but I think Emacs Org mode really helps
  + One of the groups even used LaTeX, but I think Emacs AucTeX
might be the best way to write LaTeX
```

But why does it go back all the way to the very first column? I want `might` to be aligned with the word `Org` from the previous line... Would something like Fill-mode help here (never used it)? Right now I am just doing `<space>` however many times from the first column to align words in this case, but it is rather cumbersome. You would think `TAB` would work, but it doesn't seem to unfortunately..

What is the best way to maintain alignment in this case? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I would use `auto-fill-mode`, but I feel that sometimes it is too strict in making it's judgements.

Eg. say I have this paragraph as a list item:

```
+ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit some
  gibberish here. Phasellus sed massa quam. Morbi nec sollicitudin
  nulla. Ut pharetra lacinia hendrerit. Praesent purus ex, luctus non
  erat quis, interdum vulputate justo.
```

I usually like it when sentences are on one line. So I want the sentence "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit some gibberish here." to be on the first line. However, since `auto-fill-mode`/`M-q` is strict, it won't allow me to do this.

I was wondering if there was a more general solution, like some hidden command I don't know about that creates a newline, but with the stuff after the newline being indented properly, just like `M-q`.

Comment: Hit `M-q` (`fill-paragraph`) instead of `RET` to get the effect you want.  Consider activating `auto-fill-mode` so this sort of thing happens automatically.

Comment: @FranBurstall Hmm, can you set `auto-fill-mode` to only be on in Org Mode and children only (org-journal is a child of org mode), instead of globally? Is this a good way to achieve this: `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'auto-fill-mode)`? I sort of realized that `auto-fill-mode` might be good, but was not sure how to enable it.

Comment: @FranBurstall I made some updates to the question to specify better what I'm looking for.

Comment: (1) Yr `add-hook` stanza is the right way to enable `auto-fill-mode` in just `org` buffers.  (2) Maybe `newline-and-indent` is what you are looking for.

Comment: `newline-and-indent` is probably the thing that you are looking for as @FranBurstall points out, but it is still buggy: it calls the value of `indent-line-function` which in Org mode buffers is `org-indent-line`. But `org-indent-line` seems buggy to me: in fact, the code and the description do not seem to match. I think a bug report to the Org mode mailing list is warranted.

Comment: @NickD Yes, it seems that, in Org mode (version 9.3), both `newline` and `newline-and-indent `seem to have the same behaviour (neither of which is what I am asking for in this question), which does seem like a bug. I'm not involved with the development for Org Mode - or any other many open source projects that use a mailing list - so am not familiar with how filing a bug report works. I would appreciate if you could open a bug report on my behalf.